# Count Number of items in a collection

Tags: c#, .net, collectionview

How to count items that are equal to a certain value and place it in a label ?

```
class Conversation
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Readen { get; set; }
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
}
```

In Readen property, there are values that are equal to "1" or to "0". How to count every Readen that is equal to "1" ?

Update;

tried this calling after Conversation is filled:

```
        private void CountUnread() {


        int i = 0;

       Conversation cs = new Conversation();

       if (cs.Readen == "1") {
           i++;
       }
       MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());

    }
```

MessageBox shows zero

Comment: How does your question relate to WPF or Datagrid? You should perhaps remove those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thing like this...

`Conversation cs = new Conversation();` //If you are in another class create instance

`if (cs.Readen.Equals(1))
 {
     //Your Statements Here...
 }`

Comment: tried this before, but does not work (cs.Readen is Null). Don't I have to do a loop or something to go into al the items ?

Comment: Have u assigned properly., Check the assigning place whether you are assigning properly or not...

Comment: yes, after Conversation is filled, I call this in a method. (See my post)

Comment: See @keno you are trying like this.. In `Conversation cs = new Conversation();` Here you are creating instance right.Then In Next line you have to assign.But here you are trying to get a value without assign anything. If you are creating instance for a class you have to assign some where then only values will come. Inside some method assign the value for `cs.Readen = 1;` somthing like this. Then check the `If(cs.Readen.Equals(1)) { //Your Statements Here... }`.It will work.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336768.aspx), or to be more precise, the [Enumerable.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) method:

```
IEnumerable<Conversation> items = ...
...

var count = items.Count(c => c.Readen == 1);
```

Comment: I don't get IEnumerable.. what comes behind "items="  ? :/ (Just started with wpf)

Comment: This isn't WPF, just plain .Net Framework. [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) is the base interface of all collection types in .Net, and i guess you're going to organize you `Conversation` objects in some kind of collection.

Comment: Yes, my Conversation is binded by an ObservationCollection to show into a datagrid

Comment: Then items is your ObservableCollection